# RxJava 2 and Retrofit 2 error

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2, rx-android

I'm using retrofit 2 and RxJava 2

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.12'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
```

And I'm getting this error while calling this API (**https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxx**)-

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call
>   adapter for
>   io.reactivex.Observable
>   for method APIsInterface.getHeadlines

Not able to get what is the problem even after checking again and again.
This is my code -

```
 public class RetrofitBuilder {

        private APIsInterface mAPIsInterface;

        public APIsInterface RetrofitBuilder() {

            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Config.baseURL)
                    .build();

            mAPIsInterface = retrofit.create(APIsInterface.class);

            return mAPIsInterface;
        }
    }
```

This is the APIs interface -

```
public interface APIsInterface {

    @GET("/top_headlines")
    Observable<HeadlinesBean> getHeadlines(@Query("country") String country, @Query("apiKey") String apiKey);
}
```

And this is my API call in my Activity -

```
RetrofitBuilder mRetrofitBuilder = new RetrofitBuilder();
        Observable<HeadlinesBean> observable = mRetrofitBuilder.RetrofitBuilder().getHeadlines("us", "227c9e8935bc4373b83e0908795e5696");

        observable.subscribe(new Observer<HeadlinesBean>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(HeadlinesBean headlinesBean) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
            }
        });
```

Comment: It quite specifically says that you did not add the `RxJava2CallAdapterFactory` to the Retrofit builder. And the `GsonConverterFactory` is missing, too.

Comment: But Jake Wharton says that it is not required from Retrofit 2.2 and more - https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter

Comment: Yes, it says to use the official one: https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava2

Comment: yes. Thanks a lot. I had to had the one from retrofit instead of the one from Jake Wharton's library

Answer (score 1):

I used this - .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(Config.baseURL)
                .build();
```

And its working. Thanks to @EpicPandaForce for the answer.